# Bash script for renaming files and moving into different folder

Tags: bash

I am having difficulties in wiring a bash command, that will allow me to get into all of the folders in my path, rename all of the files to `X_filename` where `X` is folder count (if first folder then 1, if second 2, etc), and `filename` is original filename. Then, I would like to move the renamed files into one directory, lets say `Desktop/dist`.

Any ideas on how I can do that?

So far I wrote something like that:

```
count=0
for i in *; do
    mv "${i}" ${count}_file.`echo "${i}" | awk -F. '{print $2}'`
    ((++count))
done
```

However, this only changes all files within the folder - it doesnt move them to the folder I wanted.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show your coding efforts.

Comment: @Cyrus, added my code

Comment: add the folder to the command...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a counter and a `for..in..do...done` loop.

Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=./files/*
TARGET=~/Desktop/dist # make sure that folder exists!
COUNTER=1 # if you want to start from 0, just put 0 there
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  mv $f $TARGET/$COUNTER"_"${f##*/}
  let "COUNTER++"
done
```

Comment: Will this go into all of the folders within my path?

Comment: Oh, I can see. It will go in all of the folders inside ./files

Comment: No, it doesn't. (Sorry, missed that) But it does copy directories as well.

Comment: Yes, you can, but you have to run the script multiple times with the required FILES setting. And make sure you add the subdirectory in the TARGET variable as well.

Comment: At present, this is badly buggy if filenames contain spaces. Quotes are important.